# why ash shift command cause whole script exit?

Tags: sh, ash

I have a script `test.sh`:

```
OUTPUT_FILE="$1"; shift || { echo "require arg1: output file path"; exit 1; }
```

But when i execute `./test.sh` without arguments, it does not output `require arg1: output file path` The output is `shift: nothing to shift`

Who can tell me why?

My ash environment: Busybox Android 2.2~4.4

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? Custom ROM often ship with `busybox`, so it's really `hush` or `ash` compiled with (limited) `bash` support, not `bash`.

Comment: sorry, i edited the script source, remove braces around shift.

Comment: thank you, i checked the android source, it's ash, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I can't reproduce your problem, the cause seems clear:
your shift doesn't raise error as exit value, to proceed with script execution, when not enough parameters were specified, but otherwise ignores that condition silently. Instead it outputs an error of its own, and terminates further script execution.

Rather than relying on shift to produce that exit value - which yours doesn't seem to - you could think of testing command line for any parameters left to shift:

```
echo "${#@}"
```

shows the length of remaining (yet unshifted) command line. If it's 0, you want your warning message. Note that while bash produces the number of command line parameters, busybox ash counts the number of characters remaining on command line.

Alternatively. test $1 for emptyness:

```
[ -z "$1" ] && echo "no args"
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems is by design of ash. Exactly use [ -z "$1" ] works in android 4+. But android 2.2-3's ash does not support "[" command, i am really unlucky. Finally i upload busybox to android then use it to execute shell script.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, "test" also not exists in some version. Forget it, it seems that ash is too weak.